# Dealing with very fast (moving) fighters

Tags: league-of-legends

As an ADC, what are some points to protect yourself from very fast melee champions (e.g. Udyr, Hecarim)? Even if you have a ward near your lane, unless you see them coming from far far away they get to you before you can retreat to your tower, CC the hell out of you and kill you very fast or chase you down and kill you. Many times they dove me under the turret, cc'ed, killed me and then just ran away with their insane speed.

Kiting against them is very difficult because they have a huge movement speed difference over me.

In team fights generally it’s OK because I stay behind my front line and I engage after they engaged on someone else, but in the laning phase (and to some point in early mid–game) they are so scary for me as ADC.

Comment: Tip 1: More map awareness

Comment: depends on elo level... try not to take the normal path could work on low elo if they have no wards in jungle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to deal with this.

- Play with more caution. Have your support ward at dragon and tri-bush constantly, get your mid to ward the ramp-bush (behind red; as purple team) or blue bush (if you're blue-team). With the new warding system introduced season 4, you might want to consider helping your support ward. If the lane is pushed just wait for it to push back, go kill the wight (big wraith thingy in jungle) or go back and heal if you have time.
- Call for ganks/counter-ganks. This doesn't work all the well if you're not friends with the jungler but if you ask nicely then it can yield the same results. If you find that you are roughly evenly matched against the other botlane and the enemy jungle keeps ganking, ask your jungler for a gank (nicely). If the lane/river is warded try a more defensive approach, ask them to stick around for when the enemy ganks (easy to predict if the enemy jungler is camping your lane).
- Get an ADC that kites well, and lane with a support with heavy CC. This one is the shakiest as it is usualy counter-productive to the team-comp but occasionally it does well. Say maybe Ashe & Leona bot lane.

**Communicate** with your team. Don't say "jungler gank!" or "if this rammus would gank our lane we wouldn't be losing" say things like "we're falling behind a little bit here rammus, could you lend us a gank?" it gets them in a better mood to want to help you. The important part is to remember to be nice even if they start at you with hostility. Getting into a flame-war, rage-fest, or w/e you want to call it helps no one but the enemy team. Just man-up and be nice, you'll win more that way.

**Pre-game** is game. The game starts the second you enter queue. Once you're in lobby you need to be thinking about how your team works well together and their weaknesses. Make sure everyone is aware of them and try to capitalize as a team.

This is, I'm aware, easier said than done. But if you do this well and try your hardest (don't surrender) then you'll surprise yourself. For example, I've laned before with someone who had litterly no experience as ADC (I was support). We still won the game, why? Because I was constantly giving them a tutorial in chat the whole game whenever we weren't fighting. I wasn't saying things like "You suck, farm better noob!" I was saying "It might be best if we focus on farming instead of fighting as we are not evenly matched against our enemy." etc. etc.

To direct this more towards answering your question directly:
Watch what others on your team are doing. If someone is chasing and they have CC. Ask them to stay by your-side (nicely) next fight and see how that goes. It doesn't always work but asking is better than not asking or worse, raging/flaming.

Comment: Good advices, ty. Regarding calling the jungler: usually these kind of champions (e.g. heca) gank very fast: they are in and out before you can even retreat, let alone call for the friendly jungler.

Comment: right, I figured this much. If you have an idea of whent hey will be ganking or just have a feeling, try asking your jungler to come bot lane and just sit a little bit. Obviously if your jungler is doing poorly this won't be much help but in some circumstances it can be.